# How would you say "for all I know" using 限り/限る in Japanese?

Tags: translation, phrase-requests

The best I can think of is 僕が知る限り + fact + とは限らない. Does this work, are there better alternatives?

Comment: Are you looking for a plain “according to the information I have”, or more like a “for all I know, he could be dead” kind of thing? There seems to be some variance on what people think the phrase means http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92207/what-is-the-correct-definition-and-usage-of-for-all-i-know

Comment: @mirka: the latter. "For all I know, this could've been zombie alien pirates" kind of thing, even.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the phrase you're looking for is more about entertaining extreme/absurd possibilities, or humorously saying how little you know about the matter, rather than a sincere “to the extent of my knowledge”.

Variations on “知る限り” will work when you are being sincere, but it doesn't really work in a sarcastic way. I'd say it's closer to a “to my knowledge” or an “as far as I know”:

> 僕の知る限りではいい人だよ
>   *As far as I know, he's a good person.*

When you're just putting out some extreme possibilities, you might consider variations on “可能性もある”. Literally, it means “there is even the possibility that…”, but I think the sentiment can be close:

- 35年という期間は長すぎて、働けなくなる可能性や、**それこそ**死んでしまう**可能性もあります**
  *35 years is such a long time, you could become unable to work, or for all you know you could be dead.*
- あの人はあまりにもよくテレビに出ていて、毎回 別人の**可能性すらある**
  *He's on TV so frequently, for all I know it could be a different person each time.*
- プロフィールは全くのデタラメの可能性もあるのです。相手が故意にウソをいってだまし、犯罪に巻き込もうとしている**可能性さえ考えられます**
  *Profiles can be completely fake. For all you know, the person may be lying to deceive you, trying to involve you in a crime.*

<sub>(Examples taken and edited from the internet.)</sub>

Answer (score 7):

I think what you have is fine, but I would say it as 私の知っている限り.

Answer (score -3):

My suggestion is "僕【ぼく】の理解限界【りかいげんかい】[と言【い】えば・について・に関【かん】して]...."

Comment: I would suggest changing 僕【ぼく】 to 自分【じぶん】 -- using 僕【ぼく】 is often inappropriate, depending on the social situation, whereas 自分【じぶん】 ("myself") is more socially neutral.  Also, 理解限界【りかいげんかい】 is not really used this way in Japanese.