# What's the difference between 限り(は) and 限りでは？

Tags: grammar

I understand that 限り(は) means that "as long as ", as in :

> 親である限り子供を第一に考えるべきです。

Moreover, I get that 限りでは means "from that area/information" the speaker draws a conclusion, as in this sentence:

> 私は知っている限りでは彼は犯罪だ。

But then I found out two examples with 知る and 限り, that seem to have been used as 限りでは:

> 私が知っている限りのことをお話しします。
>   私の知る限り、それはありません。

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29142/how-would-you-say-for-all-i-know-in-japanese/29156#_=_

Comment: `私は知っている限りでは彼は犯罪だ。` <- 「私**の**or**が**知っている限りでは彼は犯罪**者**だ」 ?